# How can I detect a column type and insert data in JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want to insert data in jdbc. I write this code:

```
int i=0;
while(i < columnCount ){
    i++; 
    stmt_ver.setString(i, x[i] );
    stmt_ver.setDate(i+1, x[i+1] );
    stmt_ver.setDouble(i+2, x[i+2] );
}
```

But I do not want to write  `setString` , or `setDate` or `setDouble`. I want to do it dynamically.
How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: use `instanceof` to know the type.

Comment: How can I use instanceof .I have to write stmt_ver.<something> ?

Comment: do you read a `ResultSet` or set the parameters of a `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: [`PreparedStatement#setObject(int, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: @MarcoForberg yes firstly I read a result set

Comment: @MadProgrammer it gives error like error converting value to BigDecimal

Comment: The values you're passing in have to mappable to the columns in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29). It takes any kind of object and the JDBC driver figures it out.

> it gives error like error converting value to BigDecimal

The data types still need to match (or be convertable) to the actual column type, of course.

Comment: But it gives error like : error converting value to BigDecimal

Comment: What kind of error exactly? What is the column type? What kind of object did you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [getColumns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method of the `DatabaseMetaData` class, to fetch the datatype of the column. This method returns a `ResultSet` object. The 5th column of this object contains the datatype of the column.

```
public int getType(Connection con, String tableName, String columnName) throws SQLException
{
    DatabaseMetaData dbmd = con.getMetaData();
    ResultSet rs = dbmd.getColumns(null, null, tableName, columnName);
    Integer type = null;
    while(rs.next())
    {
        type = rs.getInt(5);
    }

    return type;
}
```

Assuming that you have a valid `tableName` and `columnName` in your database, the `ResultSet` object should ideally contain only 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't access the DB previously you have to access the meta data.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getMetaData()

getting the columns defintion :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

And read for every column the type and doing some mapping from DB columns type to Java type.
That is basically what ORM (like Hibernate) is doing.